# Why does Visual Studio Code show that type `NonNullableUserPropertyKeys = never`?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

this my code

```
 type NonNullablePropertyKeys<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: null extends T[P] ? never : P;
  }[keyof T];

  type User = {
    name: string;
    email: string | null;
  };

  type NonNullableUserPropertyKeys = NonNullablePropertyKeys<User>;
```

Why does Visual Studio Code show that type `NonNullableUserPropertyKeys = never` ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you have not enabled the [`--strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks) compiler option.  I'd suggest you use the `--strict` compiler option (which includes `--strictNullChecks` along with some other flags that improve type safety).  It's off by default, for backwards compatibility reasons, which is really too bad.

Anyway, with `--strictNullChecks` disabled, `null` and `undefined` are assignable to every type, and therefore `null extends T[P]` is always true.  If all types are nullable, then `NonNullableUserPropertyKeys` should be `never`:

[Playground link to code with `--strictNullChecks` disabled](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOxgVwDaoIYCNUQAoBOckBoA0hCAM4A8AKgHxQC8UA3gFBRQDaeUASwRQA1pTgAzKHQC6ALigI0qKBAAewCAgAmVaXxlQA-IogA3CASgK8Abg4BfHmJCTpM+x1CQoAVSqWLOxcihgAthAKVMAEQgDm9twQYRgCqFEx8VAAPorK9g6e3tDwSMrYuP6WhMSW5JR6rKUo6BX4RCT11DRVBAy2QA)

If you enable `--strictNullChecks`, then `null` is no longer assignable to every type, and `NonNullableUserPropertyKeys` should evaluate to `"name"`:

```
type NonNullableUserPropertyKeys = NonNullablePropertyKeys<User>;
// type NonNullableUserPropertyKeys = "name"
```

[Playground link to code with `--strictNullChecks` enabled](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOxgVwDaoIYCNUQAoBOckBoA0hCAM4A8AKgHxQC8UA3gFBRQDaeUASwRQA1pTgAzKHQC6ALigI0qKBAAewCAgAmVaXxlQA-IogA3CASgK8Abg4BfHmJCTpM+x1CQoAVSqWLOxcihgAthAKVMAEQgDm9twQYRgCqFEx8VAAPorK9g6e3tDwSMrYuP6WhMSW5JR6rKUo6BX4RCT11DRVBAz2APQDUMWwiC2YOBC9NZ0gFNRBAEQI4RBLQA).

Hope that helps; good luck!