# Trying to get React Redux example in TypeScript to play well with VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, react-redux

In the Redux documentation, there is an example that is not playing well with VS Code. I am talking about the example here: https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#typing-the-connect-higher-order-component

Here is the code, after I added the import statement for react which was missing:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux'

interface RootState {
  isOn: boolean
}

const mapState = (state: RootState) => ({
  isOn: state.isOn
})

const mapDispatch = {
  toggleOn: () => ({ type: 'TOGGLE_IS_ON' })
}

const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch)

// The inferred type will look like:
// {isOn: boolean, toggleOn: () => void}
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>

type Props = PropsFromRedux & {
  backgroundColor: string
}

const MyComponent = (props: Props) => (
  <div style={{ backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor }}>
    <button onClick={props.toggleOn}>
      Toggle is {props.isOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
    </button>
  </div>
)

export default connector(MyComponent)
```

When I open that index.tsx file in VS Code, it does not find the properties:

[image]

What is wrong with the code form that example? Or is it VS Code that is having an issue?

**UPDATE:**

I tried my component on CodeSandbox and the editor on there does not complain at all. I tried to configure all the versions to be the same in CodeSandeBox and in VS Code, but I am certainly missing something. I am not sure though which part detects the property types, whether it is eslint, the TS compiler or something else.

https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-class-components-forked-js2e2h?file=/src/MyComponent1/index.tsx

Comment: Looks like the intersection of `PropsFromRedux` and `{ backgroundColor: string }` results in never... I doubt `PropsFromRedux` is actually what you have shown.

Comment: @catboykelly What do you mean about PropsFromRedux?

Comment: If possible could you reproduce your error in the playground and share it here?

Comment: @catboykelly Well, from what I see, the playground does not support TypeScript. Moreover, you would not be able to see the problem in the playground since it appears in with the VS Code linter.

Comment: I have copied your code to the playground and it works fine, so that means it is a problem with your editor. Did you try restarting VSCode or the language server? Reinstalling your linter?

Comment: @catgirlkelly Thanks for trying the code. Which playground are you talking about? Are you talking about the JavaScript/HTML/CSS Editor on Stackoverflow? Thanks for the suggestions! I did restart VS Code, but it did not change anything. I am not sure what you mean about a language server...

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + P to open Command Palette, then type "Restart", and you should be able to see "Restart TypeScript Server" or something like that. The playground I use is the one @ their site https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/Q

Comment: Thanks for that information @catgirlkelly! I restarted te TS server, but that did not help. And thanks for the playground link! :)

Comment: What's your TypeScript version in your project and VSCode? To view it in VSCode you can open up the command palette again and type "TypeScript version".

Comment: Hi @catgirlkelly! My VS Code TypeScript version is 4.6.3 whereas my workspace TS version is 4.4.4, so I told VS Code to use the workspace version now, but it is still not interpreting the code correctly in the editor. I have seen another post on SO where someone tells to enable --strictNullChecks or more globally --strict in the compiler options. I am not too sure though where that would be:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62121985/why-does-visual-studio-code-show-that-type-nonnullableuserpropertykeys-never

Comment: @catgirlkelly Nevermind, I just discovered that I could set the compiler options in tsconfig.json. I did set strictNullChecks to true, but it did not help.

Comment: I even copied the whole `compilerOptions` from my workspace to the playground tsconfig.json file and the playground editor is still fine with the code whereas VS Code is still complaining.

Comment: Talking to a colleague, I finally found out where the error is coming from. Our code is overloading the connect interface definition to get the @connect decorator working correctly. We will probably get rid of the decorator and that will solve the issue.